# Children joining train later UK

Tags: uk, trains, tickets, children, train-stations

I need to travel from London to the north and my children aged 5 and 8 will join me on the train at Milton Keynes, delivered there by their grandparents. If I book the ticket for all three of us from London it works out cheaper than a single for me from London to MK and then all three from MK to destination. But is it possible for the kids to join at MK if their ticket is from London, or will it cause problems going through the barriers and boarding at MK?

Comment: What about two singles from MK to destination and one from London? That being the actual travel that is planned.

Comment: I agree with @Jontia. Most tickets, if they're not Advance fare, will allow what's called "break of journey", allowing you to exit at any intermediary station along your valid route, and continue your journey later. This can also be done as many times as you want.

Comment: As @Muzer alluded to in their answer, I would also be concerned about how you're going to meet up with your children on the train. Is Milton Keynes manned, and will the staff allow the kids through the barriers and escort them to the train, or permit their grandparents through too? Be aware that the train would stop for only a couple of minutes. Also, I've had several occasions where you cannot access all carriages of a train from inside it.

Comment: *will it cause problems going through the barriers* Important thought

Comment: To clarify a bit of my comment further, the platform where the children are boarding from may be crowded. Even knowing beforehand which carriage you're on, they may find it difficult to be able to board that carriage. Furthermore, the carriage interior may be crowded, making it difficult to get to that carriage within the train, or the carriages may not be linked internally (if the train is becoming a split service, for instance). There's a lot of variables.

Comment: @user25730 at the moment trains in the UK are generally pretty empty.  Milton Keynes is a major staffed station and staff are generally helpful in letting passengers be escorted to the train by a non-traveller if they need assistance (e.g. children, but I've seen other examples)

Comment: Normally family+friends railcards are good; mine paid for itself in one trip.  However they're only valid while travelling together, so don't be tempted to get one if your tickets are different.  You could get one if you end up booking all together from MK with a separate journey (no railcard) London-MK.  Also station ticket office staff are usually very helpful at the planning/buying stage. At my station they're also bored from lack of customers so would have plenty of time to help (especially outside rush hour)

Answer (score 8):

It depends on the fare type.

If this is an "Advance" ticket - an inflexible ticket which requires you to travel on a specific train - then this is not, in theory, valid. There is, of course, the possibility of station staff taking pity on you, but it's not something you should rely on.

If, on the other hand, you're buying flexible tickets - (Super) Off-Peak or Anytime Singles or Returns - this would almost certainly be valid, but I'd have to know your destination to be sure (a few destinations have "break of journey" restrictions on the fare, specifically ones in North Wales).

Other things to consider:

- I assume you're travelling Avanti West Coast and want to ensure you sit together? If so could you book through their own website and specifically choose your seats? Not sure how COVID affects this ability though. That way you could buy a single London-(Destination) for yourself and two child singles Milton Keynes-(Destination) for your kids. If all else fails, due to COVID social distancing you should be able to book a table seat for yourself (if one is available) and then have your kids sit with you, even if they have reservations elsewhere on the train.
- If the worry is because you're actually using a Family and Friends Railcard, bear in mind that this is not valid if you're not travelling with kids, so your London-Milton Keynes portion would be invalid, even if you have also bought child tickets (if you don't physically have children with you, it's not valid). In this case if you want the discount your only option is to do as you suggested - a ticket London to Milton Keynes, then three tickets Milton Keynes-(Destination). If you're not considering a Family and Friends Railcard, this is something you should be considering - they cost £30 for one year or £70 for three, and give you 1/3 off adult tickets and 60% off child tickets for up to 4 adults and 4 children, as long as one of the (up to two) named cardholders is travelling along with at least one child. If you make regular rail journeys with your kids this is almost certainly worth it; and depending on how much you intend to spend sometimes it can be worth getting it even for just one journey.
- If you're travelling London Northwestern Railway they don't offer seat reservations so this should not be a concern.
- Make sure their grandparents leave plenty of time at the station, as there are ticket barriers at Milton Keynes Central. I'm sure that once the situation is explained they will be let through, or at the very least the children can be handed off to a member of staff who will see them safely onto the train, but I'd want to avoid any last-minute dashes for this reason.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if the fare type does not permit joining late (e.g. Advance fares) the ticket won't operate the barriers at MKC.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey eh, I'd be surprised if that's the case. Ticket barrier programming rarely matches actual ticket validity in my experience... usually they have a vastly simplified set of rules.

Comment: People have been forced to buy new tickets by on-train revenue protection staff when 'joining late' using Advance tickets (which are only valid between the named start & end stations), and saying 'the barrier let me through' won't cut any ice.

Comment: Furthermore, I'd ensure the grandparents stay with the children to the train. My experience with ticket barriers has been normally good, but I've had a few instances where a ticket barrier has just "eaten" my ticket and not let me through, or where I've put my ticket in to open it and someone has barged in front of me to go through, with the barrier closing behind them (not good at a destination, as then you're left ticketless behind a barrier).

Comment: @user25730 yep, definitely not suggesting the kids be sent to use the barriers on their own! My point was either the grandparents should be allowed through the barriers to see them onto the train, or if the barrier staff don't want to let them through, a member of station staff should be able to escort them through the barriers and to the train.